# Trouble with focusing an element jquery

Tags: jquery

guys :)

```
$('#loginbox').blur(function(){
    var focusedInputs = null;
    $('#loginbox table tbody tr td input').focus(function(){
        focusedInputs = this;
    });
    alert(focusedInputs);
    if (focusedInputs == null) {
        $('#loginbox').stop().fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('#loginlink').prop('href','#login');
            window.location.hash = '#';
        });
        $('#loginlink').removeClass('selected');
        $('.tooltip').css('display','none');
        Cufon.refresh();
    }
});
```

It alertrs me 'nul', but if I write alert(focusedInputs) in the focus function:

```
    $('#loginbox table tbody tr td input').focus(function(){
        focusedInputs = this;
        alert(focusedInputs);
    });
```

It alerts an element... I have no idea where is the problem... Thanks!

Comment: Why not try `$(this)` instead of `this`?

Comment: Won't the alert only have a value if the field is focused?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you really shouldn't be binding a focus event inside a blur event unless you plan on unbinding it.

```
var focusedInputs = null;
$('#loginbox table tbody tr td input').focus(function(){
    focusedInputs = this;
}); // do you also need a blur event here to clear focusedInputs?


$('#loginbox').blur(function(){
    alert(focusedInputs);    
    if (focusedInputs == null) {
        $('#loginbox').stop().fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('#loginlink').prop('href','#login');
            window.location.hash = '#';
        });
        $('#loginlink').removeClass('selected');
        $('.tooltip').css('display','none');
        Cufon.refresh();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats fine, but the focus event won't be bound until after you blur loginbox... and every time after that resulting in the event being bound n times where n is the number of times you have blured loginbox.

Comment: I need to check if any input in #loginbox is focused only when happen blur event on #loginbox.
I tryed. Null...